# addToBackStack doesn't add to fragment manager's back stack

Tags: android, android-fragments

My app has tabs and within one tab, I have a Fragment with a ListView. When an item is clicked in the list, I try to initialize a new Fragment under that tab with the following:

```
private class ShowItemClickListener implements OnClickListener {
        public void onClick(View v) {
        Fragment showDetails = new ShowFragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft = activity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.realtabcontent, showDetails);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);    
        ft.commit();
        System.out.println(activity.getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()); // this prints 0 though
    }
}
```

As a result, when I press the back button in Show Fragment view, it just closes the application instead of returning to the previous fragment. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for late answer but maybe somebody will have same question.

I was solving the same problem. It seems actual fragment is added to backstack only if this fragment isn't in current view. So it will be added to stack after when you switch to next fragment.